# Multiple sockets/streams for multithreaded server client architecture

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

Is it possible to hold multiple output and input streams for the same socket?

If not, is it possible to open e.g. two sockets on the server side and let the client connect to these, but pay attention: Multiple clients can connect at the same time, so if the client c1 connects to socket s1 and c1 also wants to connect to socket s2, but client c2 is connecting to the s2 then both client might think they connected to s1, and server treats it wrong.

How to get this working?

Comment: Just fix the server so it treats it right. If the server has a bug, fix it.

Comment: It isn't really a bug....but how can I be sure that both connections only one client can get

Comment: What do you mean? You have two connections, so ... what's the actual issue?

Comment: Why? How would 'both client might think they connected to s1'? What's the problem here?

Comment: @EJP Socket S1 and Socket S2 for S1 = data and S2 = commands/errors. Two clients C1 and C2 connecting at the same time...C1 holds S1 and C2, S2. Server thinks he is treating one client. Both clients expect a second connection.

Comment: @MarcelHöll The server can associate data sockets with command/error sockets by their remote IP address:ports. It certainly should not just rely on accept order.